# How to store php classes into mysql enum?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, enums, laravel-migrations

I'm using laravel 5.5.19 and I'm trying to save the class of a [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) like this:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('credenciable_id')->nullable();
$table->enum('credenciable_type', ["App\\Router", "App\\ATA", "App\\Antena"])->nullable();
```

But mysql enum is being created like this:

```
| credenciable_id   | int(10) unsigned                       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| credenciable_type | enum('AppRouter','AppATA','AppAntena') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

I tried to change double quotes to single quotes and double strokes to single stroke but without results.

How can I store the PHP class name into enum of MySQL using Laravel migrations?

Comment: what if you do like this in  migrations `Router", "ATA"`

Comment: Laravel polymorphic relationships needs to store id of the polymorphic table, and the class of the object that is saved into that table.

Comment: Can i store the object name 'Router' without the full class name 'App\Router' and keep it working?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Class name resolution via ::class `$table->enum('credenciable_type', [Router::class, ATA::class, Antena::class])->nullable();` ?

Comment: It creates the enum like when I asked the question. The enum field is being created like this: `enum('AppRouter','AppATA','AppAntena')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Enum` like this in your database migration file.

```
$table->enum('credenciable_type', ["Router", "ATA", "Antena"])->nullable()
```